# Latex: how to draw box around text that contains a verbatim block

Tags: latex, verbatim

Typically, to box in some text, I use the following:

```
\fbox {
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
    This is some text! Blah blah blah...
    }
}
```

However, say I have a verbatim block within that. It will never compile. Anyone know how I could draw a box around text which contains a verbatim block? Like this for example...

```
\fbox {
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
        \begin{verbatim}
        This is some text!
        \end{verbatim}
    }
}
```

I should not that I re-posted this in tex.stackexchange after [CPF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210697/cfp) pointed out that there was such a thing. Let me know if people are opposed to doubled posting. If not, I'll keep it up here as well.

Comment: Sounds like this should go to http://tex.stackexchange.com/ , shouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it should. Didn't know there was such a thing. Thanks..

Comment: It was moved to there.

Answer (score 34):

Easier: use the `fancyvrb` package.

```
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
stuff
\end{Verbatim}
```

Comment: Note that Verbatim is case sensitive and this will not work with verbatim. (Just to help anyone else that got caught by same problem as me)

Comment: The above comment is right, but to rephrase it: you really do need `Verbatim` with the upper case `V`. The normal `verbatim` will **not** work with that option.